# Sending ESC/POS commands on Windows via USB and Java

Tags: java, printing, usb, thermal-printer

I developed a Java application which sends ESC/POS commands to a thermal-printer (Sewoo LK-TL200) via serial port. I used the javax.comm library in order to locate the adequate COM port and send the data.
Commands look like this:

```
    {...}
    os = new PrintStream(port.getOutputStream(), true);

    os.write (0x1D);
    os.write ('L');
    os.write (90);
    os.write (0x00);

    os.println(t.get_cabecera());
    {...}
```

Now, we have to send the same commands to the same printer but using USB instead of RS232.
I've heard about the USB java library but it seems it's not working on **Windows**.

I've also played some minutes with javax.print library and I can detect the printer but it seems not being so trivial as serial communications and I couldn't send any command.

- Is there any way to trick Windows into thinking the USB printer is connected to a COM port?
- Some different solution to this problem I've not thought about?

I would really appreciate your help/tricks/comments.